# How to handle JSON object in php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I figure it out to create a JSON object in jquery

```
function form2JSON(form){
    var info_ser = $('#'+form).serialize();
    var data = info_ser.split('&');
    var output = {};
    $.each( data, function( i, l ){
        var data_input = l.split('=');
        output[data_input[0]] = data_input[1];
     });
    return output;
}
```

But now in PHP I dont know how to handle the JSON.... ?

Comment: And where is php here?

Comment: `$array = json_decode($json_string,true); echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);` . Now apply `foreach()` on this array

Comment: Did you figure out how to send the JSON object to the server?

Comment: Type "php json" in google search box. Then check the first 2 results.

Comment: Why are you building JSON on your own? Use `JSON.stringify(your_array);` for that

Comment: I use an Ajax function to send the data `$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./modelo/.php",
        data: { act: 'mc', ent: 'modelos', jsonobject },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) { });`

Comment: Do you have any PHP code yet? And what do you mean by "_handle_ the JSON"? Without knowing what you're trying to do with it, any attempt to answer will just be a guess.

Comment: $array = json_decode($json); This will turn your JSON object into a PHP array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./modelo/.php",
    data: {
        act: 'mc',
        ent: 'modelos',
        json: jsonobject
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
}).done(function(data) {});
```

Then you can access your data in php by:

```
json_decode($_POST['json']);
```

You actually forgot to add a key in data for your jsonobject.